# Can't figure out the right way to bind signals from qml to cpp slots

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

I'm using QT 5.7.
My `main.qml` file's root element is 'ApplicationWindow'(which btw always underlines visible, width and height as invalid properties even though they work. I'd like to know a fix for it or the proper way to do this since I can't edit it in designer).
This is its code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
    Rectangle{
    signal mSend()
    anchors.fill: parent
        Button{
            id: bSend
                onClicked: {
                    parent.mSend()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to bind the `mSend` signal to a CPP slot this way:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQuickItem>

class Chat: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

    public Q_SLOTS:
    void sendMessage(){
        qDebug() << "CPP SLOT sendMessage called";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QQuickView view(&engine, Q_NULLPTR);
    QObject *item = view.rootObject();
    Chat chat;
    if(item){
        qDebug() << "Item found";
        QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(mSend()), &chat, SLOT(sendMessage()));
    }else{
        qDebug() << "item is null";
    }

    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

But the result is `Item is null`. I've been following this [guide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) but I'm unable to tinker with QMLApplicationEngine and ApplicationWindow in QML.

TIA

**NOTE:** I'm using `Q_SLOTS` because I'm also using Boost to incorporate Socket IO library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the signal from the Rectangle to the root object:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
  id: appWindow
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  signal mSend()
  Rectangle{
    anchors.fill: parent
    Button{
      id: bSend
      onClicked: {
        appWindow.mSend()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The root object is directly available through the QQmlApplicationEngine

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

QObject *item = engine.rootObjects().first();
Chat chat;
if(item){
    qDebug() << "Item found";
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(mSend()), &chat, SLOT(sendMessage()));
}else{
    qDebug() << "item is null";
}

return app.exec();
```

Comment: Excellent! Breaks the hassle, thanks! Can you please look into the other doubt I posted about ApplicationWindow in the braces?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of digging out QML objects and messing with them from C++, I would highly recommend exposing your `Chat` object to QML. This is the way the QML and C++ integration was designed to work. You have several options to choose from. Either way, you can call `Chat::sendMessage()` directly from the `Button::onClicked` signal handler.

## QML Type

You can register `Chat` as a QML type using [`qmlRegisterType()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType), so you can create the instance in QML.

- main.cpp:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
      QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

      qmlRegisterType<Chat>("foo.bar", 1, 0, "Chat"); // <==

      QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
      engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

      return app.exec();
  }
  ```
- main.qml:

  ```
  import QtQuick 2.0
  import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
  import foo.bar 1.0

  ApplicationWindow {
      Chat {
        id: chat
      } 

      Button {
          onClicked: chat.sendMessage(...)
      }
  }
  ```

## QML Singleton Type

You can register `Chat` as a QML singleton type using [`qmlRegisterSingletonType()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-1), so you can conveniently access the same instance anywhere in QML.

- main.cpp

  ```
  static QObject *chatInstance(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *)
  {
      return new Chat(engine);
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
      QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

      qmlRegisterSingletonType<Chat>("foo.bar", 1, 0, "Chat", chatInstance); // <==

      QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
      engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

      return app.exec();
  }
  ```
- main.qml

  ```
  import QtQuick 2.0
  import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
  import foo.bar 1.0

  ApplicationWindow {
      Button {
          onClicked: Chat.sendMessage(...)
      }
  }
  ```

## Context Property

If you must create the `Chat` instance in C++, you may set it as a context property using [`QQmlContext::setContextProperty()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty) for the QML engine's [root context](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#rootContext). Notice that you must set the property *before* loading QML that references the context property.

- main.cpp

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
      QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

      QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

      Chat chat;
      engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("chat", &chat); // <==

      engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

      return app.exec();
  }
  ```
- main.qml

  ```
  import QtQuick 2.0
  import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

  ApplicationWindow {
      Button {
          onClicked: chat.sendMessage(...)
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I really liked the register type and singleton type approach. I've been a fan of singleton all this while. Thanks for being such a great help all along my questions! It's great to be answered by someone working with QT itself :)

Comment: Can you guide me on this part? 'ApplicationWindow'(which btw always underlines visible, width and height as invalid properties even though they work. I'd like to know a fix for it or the proper way to do this since I can't edit it in designer)

Comment: This has been fixed in Qt 5.7.1. A temporary workaround is to add `import QtQuick.Window 2.2`
before the controls import. Sorry for the inconvenience.